# LinQ: Multiple joins with multiple columns identifiers

Tags: c#, linq

Could you help me to understand this error message. I did something wrong for sure but what?

**The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.**

```
Res.AddRange(from jh in db.Job
             join jd in db.JobDetail on jh.number equals jd.number
             join js in db.JobSection on new { jd.number, jd.ref, jd.product } equals new { js.number, js.ref, js.Product }
             join oh in db.Order on jd.ref equals oh.ref
             join bh in db.Buyer on jh.id equals bh.id
             where jh.dateModify >= InputDate
             select jh);
```

The error come from this line

```
join js in db.JobSection on new { jd.number, jd.ref, jd.product } equals new { js.number, js.ref, js.Product }
```

Comment: change it to new { jd.number, jd.ref, Product = jd.product } equals new { js.number, js.ref, js.Product } - property names should exactly match in anonymous types.

Comment: I have the same error when I do: join js in db.JobSection on new { a=jd.number, b=jd.ref, c=jd.product } equals new { a=js.number, b=js.ref, c=js.Product }

Comment: Then check that _types_ of those columns (number, ref etc) exactly match each other. Say if one is nullable int and another is just int (or short, whatever) - it won't work. All column types and names should match _exactly_.

Comment: @Evk Yes right. One of my type is int on left side and int? on right side. What can I do? Little tricks like ?? 0 or ToString() doesn't work.

Comment: Just cast one to another. If for example jd.number is int? and js.number is int, do: new {Number = jd.number ...} equals new {Number = (int?) js.number ...}. That will have no negative effects other than satisfying the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Evk (see comments) I found a solution

1. I need to name my variables
2. I need to respect the type (even if nullable)

So correct solution is

```
Res.AddRange(from jh in db.Job
             join jd in db.JobDetail on jh.number equals jd.number
             join js in db.JobSection on new { a = jd.number, b = (int?)jd.ref, c = jd.product } equals new { a = js.number, b = js.ref, c = js.Product }
             join oh in db.Order on jd.ref equals oh.ref
             join bh in db.Buyer on jh.id equals bh.id
             where jh.dateModify >= InputDate
             select jh);
```